# AngularJS pre-populated list empty option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, selectlist

I have a list of dates getting pushed to the View on initial load, which are then used, on page load, to submit a form which loads some data that gets parsed with angularjs, as a sort of "get the stuff on this date".

Problem I'm having is, I get an empty option. It seems a common problem with a ton of solutions... if the selectlist was populated by Angular. However, wanting to keep javascript out of my views, I'm using this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Date, Model.DateList, new { ng_model = "getFormData.Date", ng_change = "getNote()" })
```

I have set a "selected" attribute in the controller. However angular does not respect that (I can understand why) and hence I need to get rid of it because on page load I need to get the first date in the list and load another piece of data with it dynamically

How would I approach solving this? Do note I am fairly new to Angular and this is a personal exercise to get a more cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hand over the responsibility of model-binding to Angular. Trying to continue doing it in MVC will result in a world of pain or hacky solutions such as referencing DOM elements within your Angular controller or serializing your MVC model as JSON within your view so it can be attached to the scope.

If you're not quite ready for a fully fledged SPA (Single Page App) and want to take a hybrid approach, my advice is to use MVC to simply your HTML (no model binding) and then MVC/Web API to return JSON that your Angular controller can request.

Comment: I don't particularly want to make one call to get dates and another call to get the contents. Do I really not have a different way around it? Also it's not so much a SPA, it's a more flexible web application.

Comment: Not really, this is how Angular was intended to be used. If you just want to add client side interactivity to an existing HTML form then you may just be better off using jQuery.

Comment: The problem is that I'm currently using jQuery. However, I have massive truckton of javascript right now and it's virtually unmaintainable due to the amount of assignments and lack of testability. Hence why I want to move to angularjs. I guess I'll just have to procure a few more actions in my controllers then. No biggie!